# Insulating old house attic with lath and plaster ceiling

Tags: insulation, roof, attic, vapor-barrier

My attic has a bunch of cardboard spanning across the ceiling joists that a mix of loose fill and batt insulation rest on.

I had to run electrical and cut through the cardboard to gain access.

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this.

Should I apply a vapor barrier between the joists, tape the gaps, and then put back the insulation?

I'm located in Canada, Ontario so we have a big swing in temperatures throughout the year.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Poly vapour barrier will fit the joists better so you can get more insulation in.  You should have ventilation for the roof deck from the soffets/bottom to the top(ridge vent).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's been a struggle to find answers on this. I'll add the poly in between the joists. I'll make sure there's room for ventilation. I also discovered someone had stuffed the roof deck vents with old t-shirts and insulation so I removed all of that out of there.